# Add Firebase to android version 3.1.2 error in dependcy

Tags: android, firebase

On my Android version 3.1.2 I have a problem in Firebase dependency and library version. When I add the Firebase to the Android using `tool->Firebase` I have error in `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1` - it appears in red color.

Please help me so I can use Firebase in my app.

Comment: show us your gradle file

Answer (score 1):

Please post your build.gradle file just in case.

I'm guessing you're using [firebase-ui](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/releases) which has a transitive dependency on 27.1.0 support libs.

Some of the options you have:

1. Downgrade your appcompat library.
2. Add all of the conflicting dependencies explicitly.
3. Just ignore it. Your app will still build and work.